# reiniciar el bucle

Tags: java, while

Hola estoy creando un juego que tengo como ejercicio, es de adivinar el numero.
El programa me funciona perfectamente, pero necesito que al final de acabar el juego, me pregunte si quiero echar otra partida o no, es decir, que venga al principio del bucle.
No sé cómo representarlo la verdad . . 
A ver si me podeis echar una mano gracias

import java.util.*;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class juego {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce los rangos");
    int rango1=entrada.nextInt();
    int rango2=entrada.nextInt();

    int aleatorio = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(rango1, rango2 + 1);

    int numero=0;
    int intentos=0;

    while(aleatorio!=numero){
        intentos++;
        System.out.println("Dime un numero");
        numero=entrada.nextInt();

    if (numero>100){

        }
        if (numero>aleatorio){
            System.out.println("Mas bajo");
        }
            if(numero<aleatorio){
                System.out.println("Mas alto");
            }
                if(numero==aleatorio){
                    System.out.println("Has acertado " + aleatorio);
                }


    System.out.println("Has necesitado " + intentos + "intentos");

    System.out.println("Juego terminado");
```

}
    }
}

---

Esto de momento todavía no lo hemos dado :(

Comment: Puedes meter el bucle en una función separada y llamarla cuando necesites iniciar el bucle

Answer (score 2):

Podrías crear un estático método en tu clase;

```
public class juego {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean seguirJugando=false;

do{
 Sring respuesta="";
 jugar();
 system.out.printLn("¿Quieres seguir jugando?");
 respuesta=teclado.readLine();
 if(respuesta=="si"){
     seguirJugando=true;
 }else{
     seguirJugando=false;
 }
  } while(seguirJugando==true);



}

public static void jugar(){

Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Introduce los rangos");
int rango1=entrada.nextInt();
int rango2=entrada.nextInt();
int aleatorio = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(rango1, rango2 + 1);
int numero=0;
int intentos=0;

while(aleatorio!=numero){
    intentos++;
    System.out.println("Dime un numero");
    numero=entrada.nextInt();

if (numero>100){

    }
    if (numero>aleatorio){
        System.out.println("Mas bajo");
    }
        if(numero<aleatorio){
            System.out.println("Mas alto");
        }
            if(numero==aleatorio){
                System.out.println("Has acertado " + aleatorio);
            }               
System.out.println("Has necesitado " + intentos + "intentos");
System.out.println("Juego terminado");

  }
 }//fin método estático
}//fin de la clase
```

No te he dado la respuesta exacta ya que no he podido probar el código, pero la idea esta ahí, espero que te sirva.

La idea es llevar todo tu "juego" a un metodo externo y hacer uso de el hasta que el usuario introduzca una respuesta distinta de si.

Comment: if(respuesta=="si"){ JAMÁS

Comment: @EduBw no logro entender la aportación de tu comentario :S

Comment: Que eso jamás se debe hacer :P

Comment: Creo que @EduBw se refiere a usar un `respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si")`

Comment: Para mayor limpieza de código y evitar una interacción yo eliminaría la variable `seguirJugado` y utilizaría un `while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si"))` reduces la creación y el mapeo de una variable y si quieres hilar mas fino, directamente: `teclado.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("si")` eliminamos también un String

Comment: Intente realizar el ejemplo lo mas legible posible para un usuario que está empezando, entiendo...